# Is there a way to set a "NSFW" filter on Facebook?

Tags: facebook-pages

I have a page on Facebook to show off my artwork. I will admit, that some of my artwork is NSFW, or at least might attract some undesirable comments if not explicitly stated about the content.

Is there a way that I can create a "NSFW Filter" on my content, similar to a "Spoiler" tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook apparently hasn't specifically implemented the power for you to choose if it's SFW or not, so you'll have to be creative with some kind of workaround. I'm thinking apply some kind of blur in a parent comment with a NSFW label and then you can post the real, uncensored image in a child comment, or an imgur link in its stead.